# What is the R equivalent to the SAS Enterprise Miner Score Node?

Tags: r, scoring

The SAS Enterprise Miner has something called a "Score Code Node." This node applies all of the previous code (i.e. creating new variables, imputing missing values, and running the model etc.) to a completely untouched data set. How do I do this in R other than just using a hold out sample (i.e. test data)?

Comment: Interesting question but for R users who do not know an inch of SAS it could be great to see just a piece of data before and after the transformations of the code you are talking about. Just to have a glance of what it does. I think that will help R users to understand what this so called score code node does and then translate it in R language.

Comment: When you have a process in SAS, the score node keeps track of all the steps to the final model - all transformations, imputations, drop variables and creates a set of code that allows you to rerun the entire process on data in the same form as your starting data set.

Comment: If R doesn't have anything and I doubt it will you'll want to check into what Rattle offers.

Comment: @SabDeM By StackOverflow custom, code conversion does not imply a tag in the original language, so [tag:sas] is inappropriate here.

Comment: @Joe Thank you, I did not know that.

Comment: I doubt there is something like that. The fact that R gives you a lot of control over what you do comes with some setbacks, namely that you have to do many things by hand. However, it would be interesting to know if something like that does exist! You will probably be constrained by one package if it does, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Rattle GUI, as noted in the paper:

> The underlying R code, constructed and executed
>   by Rattle, is recorded in the Log tab, together with
>   instructive comments. This allows the user to review
>   the actual R commands. The R code snippets can also
>   be copied as text (or Exported to file) from the Log
>   tab and pasted into the R console and executed. This
>   allows Rattle to be deployed for basic tasks, yet still
>   access the full power of R as needed (e.g., to fine-tune
>   modelling options that are not exposed in the interface).

http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009-2/RJournal_2009-2_Williams.pdf

http://rattle.togaware.com/